# Why is UInt64 max equal -1 in Swift?

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop, swift-playground

Using Swift, wether in terminal or playground, when I enter the following on a new line:

```
UInt64.max
```

I get a result value of -1.

Is this a bug?

---

**Edit:** Examples

```
$ xcrun swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> UInt64.max / 2
$R1: UInt64 = 9223372036854775807
  2> UInt64.max / 2 + 1
$R2: UInt64 = -9223372036854775808
  3> UInt64.max
$R3: UInt64 = -1
  4> println(UInt64.max / 2)
9223372036854775807
  5> println(UInt64.max / 2 + 1)
9223372036854775808
  6> println(UInt64.max)
18446744073709551615
```

Comment: How do you check the return value?

Comment: I meant just typing it in a playground line or Swift terminal - updated question.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the playground implementation: they re-interpret it as something else (either a signed int64 or even int32). What do you get for `UInt64.max/4`?

Comment: obviously it is caused by integer overflow and most likely a bug so you should file a bug report : https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 4,611,686,018,427,387,903

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 So they print it as `Int64` then. It's a bug.

Comment: Thank you both. Filed radar: 17314071

Comment: `println(UInt64.max)` that does not give `-1` at all. how do you get that value?

Comment: @holex looks like it is a playground and lldb bug only (I hope). So if you just type UInt64.max in a line in playground or Swift terminal or lldb at a break, you get the -1.

Comment: @Spectravideo328, I've not been able to try any playground stuff, regarding the Xcode6 directly crashes on my computer, if I open any playgound.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is a bug of terminal and playground.

But, the output of the println is correct(18446744073709551615) in both terminal and playground.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same bug I've run into with any unsigned type.

echo "UInt8(255)" | xcrun swift

will also print -1

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Swift 2.1.1 : `echo "UInt8(255)" | xcrun swift` now outputs `$R0: UInt8 = 255`

Comment: or optionally: `echo "UInt8.max" | xcrun` swift now outputs $R0: UInt8 = 255

Answer (score -1):

This is still a bug, even with the REPL in Swift 2.2. See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1007 or https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1138.

Fixed in Playgrounds with XCode 7.3 though.

Answer (score -2):

It's because your processor is of 64 bit and UInt is 64 bit * 2.
The type Int can't run this number, it's out of range.

Comment: That is not true, UInt = UInt64, which is exactly 64 bits.