# Why UInt64.max / 2 + 1 represented in the memory the same as Int64 value -9 223 372 036 854 775 808 but not as -1?

Tags: swift, memory, cpu

UInt62.max / 2 is represented by 0100..0000 in the memory. Add 1 and it will be 0100..0001. So, the first bit for the sign. And we take -1. But CPU thinks that it's -9 223 372 036 854 775 808. Why does it work so complexly?

You can see that it's truth because of the issue in the Swift playground: [Why is UInt64 max equal -1 in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218918/why-is-uint64-max-equal-1-in-swift)

```
var max = UInt64.max / 2 + 1 // playground shows -1 because it treats it as Int64
```

Comment: What?  can you please demonstrate with some code?

Comment: You better to answer but not to down vote for the interesting question.

Comment: look into two's complement representation.

Comment: "UInt62.max / 2 is represented by 1000..0000 in the memory." -- No, it's not. Not even if you meant 64 rather than 62.

Comment: The sample in the question is fixed. Demo code added. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: It is not an interestin question, you need to do some studying about the actual representation of numbers (and presumably other things) in memory. Also the size if int, uint, UInt64, Int64.

Comment: In my Playground (Xcode 7.1 beta 2) it shows 9223372036854775808.

Comment: Xcode 7.0 shows wrong value. Does 7.1 beta 2 work with iPhone? Xcode 7.1 beta 1 doesn't.

Comment: No, it's just issue in the playground - see the provided link in the question.

Comment: @Altaveron Open the Apple Calculator, command-3 will take you tothe programmer version. It displays in decimal (20) and hexadecimal (16). Take some time playing withthat to get a better understanding of the number representations.

Comment: Yes 7.0 shows wrong result. That suggests that it is a bug that has been fixed. I did not try 7.1 b2 with a device yet, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in fact `-1` is not represented as `1` with a sign bit, but rather as all bits set to one. This is called a "two's complement" representation, and is used in most of the modern processors.

Read more about it here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

One of the reasons for that is that this way arithmetic operations that involve both negative and positive numbers are easier. If `-1` was represented as `1` with a sign bit, and we attempted to add `1` to it in a naive way, we would get `2` with a sign bit instead of zero. With two's complement representation you can just add the numbers as if they were unsigned, and get the correct result.

Comment: See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKTsv6iVxV4

Comment: It also makes mathematically as -1 > -2 so -1 should have a larger bit pattern.

Comment: To expand on the "it's easier" part, crucially this means that the same [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) circuit can be used for both addition and subtraction, calculating addition as `ADD(a,b,carry=0)` and subtraction as `ADD(a,~b,carry=1)`.

Comment: There's also some more explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that 1111 + 1 = (1)0000. So 1111 must be -1. Then -1 + 1 = 0.

Comment: There is no -1 in UInt64